# How to rename multiple files in Bash Scripting?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting, bash-functions

Suppose i want to rename 3 files in the same directory.
Example: 
test1.gzip
test2.gzip
test3.gzip

Now want to rename all the above files to something like,

test1_20180518.gzip 
test2_20180518.gzip 
test3_20180518.gzip

Now how can get the result? Someone please help!!

Please tell me, how to do that in bash scripting?

Comment: What happened when you tried? What are the zip file names? You know you can only rename one file at a time?

Comment: In the title you say “gunzip” but in the body you say “zip” — what are they?

Comment: Also, gunzip is a verb; it expands the contents of a gzip file. Are you trying to do that, or rename, or what?

Comment: @RedPhoenix: If you are renaming, then have you a pattern for future name?

Comment: I can rename a single file by using "mv" but i couldn't do that in the case of multiple files.My question is how to rename multiple files?

Comment: @Red, please show a couple of sample filenames, and what they should be renamed to. Also, you might want to check the `rename` man page.

Comment: You might also want to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Suppose i want to rename 3 files in the same directory,Example:
test1.gzip
test2.gzip
test3.gzip

Now want to rename all the above files to something like,
test1_20180518.gzip
test2_20180518.gzip
test3_20180518.gzip

Now how can get the result? Someone please help!!

Comment: Search this site for "[rename multiple files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=rename+multiple+files)" and you'll find lots of similar questions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information, which should also include where you get those dates from.

Answer (score 1):

Check your "rename" version with `rename -V`. If you see:

- "`util-linux`" then

  ```
  rename .gzip _$(date "+%Y%m%d").gzip *.gzip
  ```
- "`File::Rename`" then

  ```
  rename 'chomp(my $date = `date "+%Y%m%d"`); s/\.gzip/_$date.gzip/' *.gzip
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Posible solution (you need chose one in loop body):

```
#!/bin/bash

pattern="pattern"
i=0

for file in `find <your_path> -type f -name '*.zip'`
do
    extension="${file##*.}"
    filename="${file%.*}"

    # without extenstion
    mv "$file" "$filename-$pattern.$extension"

    # whole filename
    mv "$file" "$pattern-$i"
    i=$((i + 1))
done
```